# Angular 2 Post Form to External Link

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I am new in Angular 2. It seems to be starnge, but I need to send `form` to external link, moreover, I need to redirect user to this page after post request...

```
<form id="Form" method="post" action="http//somelink.com" target="TheWindow">
    <input type="hidden" name="linkname" value="someValue" />
</form>
```

Before I made that request by JQuery like that:

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {

        $( ".btnUpgrade" ).on( "click", function(){
            window.open('', 'TheWindow');
            document.getElementById('Form').submit();
        });

    });
</script>
```

But now I'm stuck and no idea how to do that in Angular 2. I read a lot of topics but they been helpless. I tried `window.location.href = '...';` but it's good only for Get request and useless for post. Any help appreciated.

**UPDATE**
What I tried(in Service):

```
submitHiddenForm() {
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers = this._httpClient.createCustomHeader();
    var url = 'http//somelink.com';
    var body = 'linkname=someValue';
    return this.http.post(url, body, headers).map(this.extractData).catch(this.handleError);
}
```

In component:

```
submitHiddenForm() {
    this._upgradeService.submitHiddenForm().subscribe (data => {
            window.location.href = 'http://somelink.com'; },
        error => {console.log('Error while redirecting!'); });
}
```

I have error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://somelink.com. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.
```

In my POST request I have such Headers:

```
createCustomHeader(): Headers {
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'origin, x-requested-with, x-http-method-override, content-type');
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST');
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
    return headers;
}
```

Comment: Simply make POST request on form submit. After post is resolved make redirect. Pretty straightforward, not clear what your problem is.

Comment: I can send POST request to any URL, but how I make POST+redirect together? Can you show real example?

Comment: POST is going to return a promise/observable. Subscribe to it and make redirect once it's complete.

Comment: `this._service.submitHiddenForm().subscribe (data => {
                window.location.href = 'http//somelink.com'; },
            error => {console.log('Error while redirecting!'); });`
Do you mean something like this?

Comment: Yes, something like this. So you already have something, it should work.

Comment: Pls see my update.

Comment: is cors enabled at somelink.com?

Comment: So you need to enable CORS.

Comment: How do I check if CORS is enabled on somelink.com? Because it's 3rd party website...
Pls see my headers of POST request.

Comment: Hey @Popeye! Did you find any solution for your question?

Answer (score -2):

try this on the basis of status code of post request

```
this.http.request(new Request(this.requestoptions))
.subscribe(res => {
        if (res[0].status == 201) {
          this.router.navigateByUrl('..URL here..');
        }
        console.log(res[0].json);
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
      })
```